# Excel Checkbook Setup

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am trying to setup excel in the following manner. Sheet1 is a list of family checking accounts. Sheet2 is my checking account, sheet3 is my moms, etc. (I have full permission from family members to track this information, plus I am on their accounts, so this is not a problem.) For this rest of this question, I will just be referencing Sheet1 and my checking account (Sheet2)

I have a formula to create a running balance for my checking account, so I can always go to that sheet, scroll down, and see the total.

What I would like to do is have cell B2 on Sheet1 auto-populate with the running balance from Sheet 2. I can't direct reference a cell on Sheet2, because more rows are added with each withdrawal/deposit.

One option I figured out was to use this formula on Sheet1:

```
=Sheet2!E2 - SUM(Sheet2!C:C)+SUM(Sheet2!D:D)
```

(BTW, just came up with that as I was typing this question)

However, I now have excel calculating a running total on Sheet1 and on Sheet2. Is there another way that I can do this so that the running total is only calculated once, but used in both places?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the running total at the top of the sheet 2 so that it doesn't move as new items are added. That way your source is always in a fixed location.

Comment: So, instead of having a balance column, just keep a running balance cell at the top of Sheet2? That could work. Is it safe to assume that if I want the running balance cell and the balance column on Sheet2, that Excel is just going to have to figure out the balance twice?

Comment: Have a balance column, just have a fast reference that shows the current balance at the top, it's easier to find than scrolling all the way to the bottom.